# Is there any document to work on Core animations and core graphics in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c

I am new to core graphics in iphone can anyone suggest how to work on that and the process to go through it.Also can any one provide me a document with sample codes.

Thanks in advance.
Monish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Core Graphics](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html#section=Frameworks&topic=Core%20Graphics) section in iOS Reference Library - you can find [Quartz 2D Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html), class references, and some samples there.

P.S. Same applies for CoreAnimation as well - there's whole relevant section in Apple's docs

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would be:

[Introduction to Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

There are a few examples there too.

What do you plan to use Core Animation for? If you are going to take a stab at make games Core Animation is a valid choice as long as performance is not critical. Here is a good article about it [here](http://maniacdev.com/2009/07/iphone-game-programming-coreanimation-vs-opengl-es/).

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I am learning CoreData myself right now, and I found the most useful document to be the [Locations App tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html).

In this tutorial, you create an app called Locations which utilizes CoreData utilities and also teaches you how to do TableViewControllers.

Good luck!